# Unable to access property of NSArray in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, arrays, import

I'm trying to pass an NSArray containing strings for use in another class than the one in which it is generated. Therefore I have made it a property as following:

loginController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>  

@interface loginController : NSObject {  
NSArray *myArray;  
}  

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * myArray;  

@end
```

loginController.m

```
#import "loginController.h"  

@implementation loginController

@synthesize myArray;  

@end
```

The question is how the interface and implementation files of the class in which I want to access myArray should look like. At this moment the interface file looks as following:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>  
#import "loginController.h"  

@interface viewController : NSObject {  
NSArray* myArray;  
}  

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray* myArray;  

@end
```

I'm not sure if this is correct and how to implementation should look if I want to use myArray in it. Can somebody help?

Comment: Off-topic: Class names should be title-cased in objective-c.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have a fundamental misunderstanding as to how properties work, or what they're for.  They're simply generated getters and setters.  They don't make objects automagically visible from any class in the program.

See [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/chapter_5_section_1.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If your `LoginController` had a reference to your `ViewController` object, you could do something that is along these lines in your `LoginController` class:

```
#import "loginController.h"  

@implementation loginController

@synthesize myArray;
@synthesize myViewController; // this property needs to be
                              // declared in loginController.h

// This method represents some hypothetical method that
// would be invoked at some point after both 'myViewController'
// and 'myArray' have been instantiated and initialized
// (for example it could be 'awakeFromNib').
-(void)someMethod
{
    myViewController.myArray = myArray;
}

@end
```

However, I want to caution you that it might not be a good architectural decision to have your `LoginController` and your `ViewController` know about each other. I only post this code as an example of how to actually pass the array between two objects; in most designs, I would think that both `LoginController` and `ViewController` are subordinate to some containing object (such as an application-level controller, for example), which would be the object setting `myArray` on the two controller instances.